# How to get the frequency of each time stamp during read file and reduce the memory

Tags: arrays, c, file, memory

I stuck in memory limit exceed because I use a naive method to finish the task which is creating a array with size 2^25. By using the index of the array to represent the timestamp, I can locate the timestamp and add its occurrence in O(1) time, but it waste lots of memory. So I want to know if there are any method that can reduce the memory.
The time stamp will group by hour by time_stamp - (time_stamp % 3600), it will minus start_time to avoid index overflow.

How to reduce the memory used and read the timestamp&occurrence quickly?
*the input timestamps can in any order

```
#define max_entry 2 << 25
#define start_time 1645491600
struct pair
{
    long timestamp;
    int occurrence;
};

struct pair *counter_array = (struct pair *)calloc(max_entry, sizeof(struct pair)); // declear pair array

//readfile
char *temp;
 
while (fgets(buffer, buffer_size, common_file) != NULL)
{
     char *temp;
     long time_stamp = strtol(buffer, &temp, 10);                                                               
     counter_array[time_stamp - (time_stamp % 3600) - start_time].timestamp = time_stamp - (time_stamp % 3600);
     counter_array[time_stamp - (time_stamp % 3600) - start_time].occurrence += 1;                           
}
```

I know using max_entry is not good, but I really can't figure out how to modify it.

Comment: One possible way to implement a histogram is a *multi-set*, where each unique value is stored together with a counter. It's a pretty standard computer-science data-structure and there's plenty of documentation about them (as well as other tutorials and examples) all over the Internet.

Comment: Aren't these timestamps naturally sorted?

Comment: the input timestamps can in any order

Comment: What's the max-value that a timestamp can take?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Since you're rounding `time_stamp`s to `hours`, just use

```
time_stamp_index = (time_stamp - start_time) / 3600;
```

2. Modify your `struct` to store frequency & hours :

```
struct hour_freq {
    int hours;
    int freq;
};
```

3. If `time_stamp` can go up to `INT_MAX` (2<sup>31</sup> - 1) i.e. `2147483647`. Then `max_index` will be

```
max_index = (2147483647 - 1645491600) / 3600 = 139,442
```

well within memory limits of `50 MiB`. With 45 MiB you can index `time_stamp`s upto `22,879,155,600`.

```
(( 22879155600 − 1645491600 ) ÷ 3600 ) × 8 = 47,185,920 octets = 45 MiB
```

4. To find frequency of a `time_stamp` at `hour` granularity, calculate `time_stamp_index` and lookup.